# Does Windows console supports ANSI?

Tags: windows, console, ansi-escape

Does the Windows console supporsts ANSI control characters?

Comment: I mean ANSI control characters

Comment: You mean ANSI **escape sequences** for coloring and cursor positioning?

Comment: Yes, it's just for coloring and cursor positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't support many ANSI control characters by default (which is also mentioned in the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), but there are ways to make that possible.

Look into the answers to this question: [How to load ANSI escape codes or get coloured file listing in WinXP cmd shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946546/how-to-load-ansi-escape-codes-or-get-coloured-file-listing-in-winxp-cmd-shell)
You might happen upon something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to ASCII control characters.

The answer is "some". You can read backspace keypresses, for example, and you can pipe-in things like the ASCII "Bell" character.

However if you mean that the Windows console automatically resolves escaped characters, such as converting "\b" into "Bell", then no, you have to do that yourself.

Note that I speak about entering keypresses directly into the console and not batch files, for that see @ProblemFactory's answer.